# Apache Pig AVG Function

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, average

I'm trying to do a simple Pig query where I need to find the average rating for the movie with id 178.  I've tried a number of versions of the below and the filter is working but not the AVG function.  Can anyone advise?  Thanks

```
a = load '/user/pig/u.data' AS (userid:int, movieid:int, rating:double, timestamp:chararray);  
b = FOREACH a GENERATE AVG(rating) as rate, movieid;
c = group b by rate;
d= filter a by movieid==178;
dump d;
```

Comment: First filter, then group, then average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group by movieid

```
b = FILTER a BY (movieid == 178);
c = GROUP b BY movied;
d = FOREACH c GENERATE group AS movieid,AVG(a.rating) as rate;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!